# Как конвертировать HEX адресс кошелька в BASE58CHECK

Tags: php, c#, hex

проблема заключается в том, что не могу получить адресс кошелька в формате BASE58CHECK.

На этом сайте все работает правильно, я нашел скрипты на PHP, GO, JAVA но нигде нет на C#
https://www.btcschools.net/tron/tron_tool_base58check_hex.php
Со строки 41ba133a7e9094ec3b0b2459561e773a2a81c1724d в строку TSw5ikxGCfts2yyRKz1zSetAPt6bL2Crqy

Я начал переписывать код с PHP на С# вручную, однако возникли ошибки при кодировке:

```
string data = "41ba133a7e9094ec3b0b2459561e773a2a81c1724d";
string address = hex2bin(data);           
byte[] _address = hex2binbytes(data);
string h_fromByteToString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_address);
byte[] h_fromStringToByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(h_fromByteToString);
```

При записи с байтов в строку, и после с полученной строки в байты, я получаю совсем другие байты, а далее надо использовать SHA256 и на этом моменте остановился.

Может кто подсказать готовые библиотеки для конвертации, или как поступить в данном случае с кодом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, не надо было байты каждый раз кодировать, надо с ними же и работать. Вот готовый код, возможно кому-то пригодиться (немного подправил):

Base58: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Base58/1.0.0?_src=template

```
    static string Res(string data)
    {               
        byte[] address = Convert.FromHexString(data);
        var hash0 = SHA256.HashData(address);
        var hash1 = SHA256.HashData(hash0);
        var checksum = hash1[..4];
        var res_bytes = address.Concat(checksum).ToArray();
        return Base58.Encode(res_bytes);
    }
```

Comment: `hex2binbytes` это вообще зачем? Есть же встроенная `byte[] bytes = Convert.FromHexString(text);`, а метод можно выкинуть

Comment: А хэш посчитать можно в 1 строку `return SHA256.HasData(input);`

Comment: О, благодарю за подсказку, раньше таким не пользовался)

Comment: `GetBytesCount` - `return bytes[..count];`

Comment: `SumByteArrays` - `return array1.Concat(array2).ToArray();`

Comment: А можно ссылку где описывается такой синтаксис, это в .net 6.0?

Comment: Да 6 и его предшественники. Про индексы в квадратных скобках читайте про `System.Range`. А последнее - простой Linq

Comment: Благодарю, упростили мой код до нескольких строк)